What time of day was the full moon of lunation zero?
According to NASA the next full moon is on December 15, 2024 at 9:02 pm UCT, JDN 2460659.875. Lunation zero is 1262 lunations earlier.  NASA'S value of 1 synodic month is
S = 29.530588 days
I wanted to know the time of day of the full moon of December 1922, and I performed the following calculation:
2460659.875 - 1262×29.530588 = 2423392.272.
That's about 30 minutes after 6:00 pm.
My problem is, I checked this site, and it has the December 1922 full moon on December 4, 1922 at 6:24 am.  So my question is what time of day was the full moon of lunation zero?

According to Chapront (2002) the mean synodic month at the epoch J2000.0 is ~29.530588861 days, but the actual synodic month length varies from that in a complex way, as I explain in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55112/16685 You can use the mean value to estimate the time between lunations, but you need much more complex calculations to get the precise time.

From JPL Horizons, there was a Full Moon on 1922-Dec-04 11:23:17.554 UT = JDN 2423392.974508728, with the Sun at ecliptic longitude 251.5408784, latitude -0.0000928 °, and the Moon at long 71.5408784°, lat -4.8445811° (geocentric).

I did the same math using Excel: 12/15/2024 21:02 UTC - 1262*29.530588 = 12/4/1922 6:35 UTC.
That would be 6:35 am, not pm.
Depending on what time zone you are in, the link to Calendar-12.com may be showing times based on your local time zone. For me, it comes up in the time zone for America/New York. 6:24 am Eastern time = 11:24 UTC.

11:24 UTC agrees with U.S Naval Observatory calculation of 11:23 UTC.

The difference of 5 hours between 6:35 UTC (our calculation) and 11:23 UTC (U.S. Naval Observatory) is because the synodic period of 29.530588 is the average over a long time. The synodic period from month to month does vary by several hours from the mean. A difference of 5 hours is within that variation.
